# URIs in REST API endpoints according to Restful practices

Tags: api, rest, microservices, multi-tenant, endpoint

I am planning to have these endpoints for our REST APIs.

1. PUT /tenant/:tenantId/users/save/:username
2. POST /tenant/:tenantId/users/invite
3. GET /tenant/:tenantId/users/fetch
4. GET /tenant/:tenantId/users/fetch/:username
5. PATCH /tenant/:tenantId/users/activate/:username
6. POST /tenant/:tenantId/groups/save/

Verbs such as save/fetch/activate are from the consistency point of view.  Are these RESTFul according to the REST principles? How should these be changed if at all? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [REST Resource Naming Guide](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/):

> RESTful URI should refer to a resource that is a thing (noun) instead of referring to an action (verb) because nouns have properties which verbs do not have – similar to resources have attributes.

And also

> URIs should not be used to indicate that a CRUD function is performed. URIs should be used to uniquely identify resources and not any action upon them. HTTP request methods should be used to indicate which CRUD function is performed.

So let's take your first URI as example

`PUT /tenant/:tenantId/users/save/:username`

Here you are using the verb **save**. As mentioned before you *should not be indicating a CRUD operation* in the URI, in this case using a POST would be more appropriate.[Here](https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/) is a guide with the purpose of each HTTP verb. Knowing this, I think that for example a more appropriate URI for that case would be something like

`POST /tenants/:tenantId/users/:username`

In this cases:

`GET /tenant/:tenantId/users/fetch`

`GET /tenant/:tenantId/users/fetch/:username`

you should remove the **fetch** because you are already telling through the GET verb that data is being fetched. Same goes for the 6th example.

But, this doesn't mean that you can't use verbs in your URIs, in fact there is a specific category called **controller** which as mentioned in the same guide:

> A controller resource models a procedural concept. Controller resources are like executable functions, with parameters and return values; inputs and outputs.
> Use “verb” to denote controller archetype.

This controllers resources could go well (I asume) with for example your

`GET /tenant/:tenantId/users/activate/:username`.

But I would think that the verb **activate** should go last:

`GET /tenant/:tenantId/users/:username/activate`

Comment: Thanks. I have updated those as follows: 1. PUT /tenant/:tenantId/users/:username

2. POST /tenant/:tenantId/users/invite

3. GET /tenant/:tenantId/users

4.  GET /tenant/:tenantId/users/:username

5. PATCH /tenant/:tenantId/users/:username/activate

6.  POST /tenant/:tenantId/groups/

Comment: If the first one is an Update I think everything is ok. Another important thing is that *Consistency is key* be consistent in the naming of you resources

Comment: Also, If I had to have an endpoint to return groups a user is in, should it be /tenant/tenantId/users/userId/groups OR /tenant/tenantId/groups/users/:userId ? Technically speaking groups are higher in the hierarchy than the users but having groups before users/:userId sounds a bit odd. what is the right way?

Comment: Yes, you should use the query component for that. for example:

GET /tenant/:tenantId/groups?user=username.

And also, if tenant is a collection it should be named **tenants**

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!!

Comment: Also, should it be /tenant/:tenantId/invite  or /tenant/:tenantId/users/invite to invite a user?

Comment: It depends, the invite action is executed over the tenant or the users of a given tenant?

Comment: users of a given tenant

Comment: In that case I think it would be more appropriate to call ./tenant/:tenantid/users/invite

Answer (score 0):

First note: [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers.  Once you figure out the right resources, you can choose any identifiers for them that you like (so long as those identifiers are consistent with the production rules defined in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A)).

"Any information that can be named can be a resource" ([Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1)), but its probably most useful to think about resources as abstractions of documents.  We use HTTP as an application protocol whose application domain is the [transfer of documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=188s).

- GET

This is the method we use to retrieve a document

- PATCH
- PUT
- POST

These methods all indicate requests to *edit a document* (specifically, to edit the request target).

PUT and PATCH are each ask the server to make its copy of a document look like the client's local copy.  Imagine loading a web page into an editor, making changes, and then "saving" those changes back to the server.

POST is less specific; "here's a document that we created by filling in a web form, edit yourself appropriately".  [It is okay to use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post): after all, the web was catastrophically successful and we're still using POST in our form submissions.

The useful work is a [side effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=188s) of these edits.

---

> Are these RESTFul according to the REST principles?

Do they work like a web site?  If they work like a web site: meaning you follow links, and send information to the server by submitting forms, or editing the webpages and submitting your changes to the server, then it is REST.

A trick though: it is *normal* in REST that a single method + request uri might have *different* useful side effects.  We can have several different HTML forms that all share the same Form.action.  Uploading changes to an order document might have very different effects if the edits are to the shipping address vs to the billing information or the order items.

Normal doesn't mean obligatory - if you prefer a resource model where each form request goes to a specific resource, that can be OK too.  You get simpler semantics, but you support more resources, which can make caching trickier.